# how should i use select tag dropdown from angular2-material design for angular2-app

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I am using  [@angular2-materail](https://www.npmjs.com/~angular2-material) components to build my application and to format form input elements. I am using `md-input`, `md-checkbox` etc but haven't found any component to display a select dropdown. Is there any component which i can use to format `select` dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is an `md-select` in development, it's not available yet. But you can track the current advancement in this issue : [angular2-material issue 118](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/118).

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```js
//Your component

import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'select-form-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-form-example.html',
})
export class SelectFormExample {
  selectedValue: string;

  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
}
```

```html
<form>
  <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
    <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>

  <p> Selected value: {{selectedValue}} </p>
</form>
```